# What is the length of pair of wires after twisting them around each other?

Tags: geometry

> Given two wires each of diameter D and length L, what will be the new length after you twist the wires around each other 1 Turn?

I mean that when you start with the pair of straight wires and put them against a scale, the length is L. When you twist them around each other tightly, and place the straightened twisted wire against the scale, its new length will be reduced.

And what I mean by 1 Turn is that looking at the cross-section, if you begin with the Red wire on top, Black at bottom then after half Turn the Red wire is at bottom and after another half Turn (or Total 1 Turn) the Red is on top again. And both wires are twisting in same direction, say clockwise, when looking at the cross-section. Successive cross-sections will look like the number 8 rotating.

I suppose we should also give the pitch? But when you play with an actual mouse wire, twisting it around itself, you will realize that you can not reduce the pitch beyond a certain extent. So what is that minimum pitch when twisting the wires? What is causing that restriction? Can it be quantified?

Perhaps the question is not too clear, so please feel free to edit/clarify.

Comment: As a practical example I twisted 3 filaments of PVC covered connecting wire starting 4 metres long using a manual hand drill on a warm day. The outside diameter of the insulation on each of the 3 wires was ~2.5mm. The final twisted length was 11.9 metres.
: That is a helix pitch angle sin(theta) ~ 11.9/14 ~0.85 i.e. theta ~58 degrees. Conversely when I cut some more I'll allow 1/0.85 - equivalent to 18% to 20% extra - so as to be close to my final required length

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The axis of each wire will take the shape of a [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) of radius $D/2$ and height $H$. The length of each helix is (for one turn)
$$
L=\sqrt{H^2+\pi^2 D^2}
$$
and we can invert this to obtain the desired new length:
$$
H=\sqrt{L^2-\pi^2 D^2}.
$$
This is the vertical distance between the centers of the end sections of a wire, total length will be $H+D\cos\theta$, where the slope $\theta$ of a wire (called "pitch" in the question) is given by $\tan\theta={H\over\pi D}$ (see figure).

[image]

As for the minimum slope, my previous answer was not correct. Experimenting with GeoGebra, it seems that $\theta_\min=45°$, which is the slope in the figure.

EDIT.

The equations of the two helices, if $a=D/2$ and $b=H/(2\pi)$, can be written as:
$$
(a\cos t, a\sin t, bt),\quad (-a\cos t, -a\sin t, bt),\quad 0\le t\le 2\pi.
$$
Let's take any point on the first helix, e.g. $P=(a,0,0)$ (corresponding to $t=0$). Its distance $s$ from any point on the second helix is:
$$
s(t)=\sqrt{2a^2(1+\cos t)+b^2t^2},\quad 0\le t\le 2\pi.
$$
The wires don't intersect if $s\ge2a$, but it's easy to check that the minimum of $s(t)$ is $s(0)=2a$ only if $b\ge a$. On the contrary, if $b<a$ the minimum of $s(t)$ occurs when $t$ is the root of ${\sin t\over t}={b^2\over a^2}$, and this minimum is strictly less than $2a$.

For the wires not to intersect, we must therefore require $b\ge a$, which translates in a bound on the slope:
$$
\tan\theta={b\over a}\ge1,\quad\text{i.e.}\quad \theta\ge45°.
$$

EDIT.

Here's the GeoGebra code to draw the two surfaces in the figure above:

```
Surface((a cos(t), a sin(t), b t) + r cos(u) (cos(t), sin(t), 0) + r sin(u) (b sin(t), -b cos(t), a) / sqrt(a² + b²), t, 0, 2π, u, 0, 2π)

Surface((-a cos(t), -a sin(t), b t) + r cos(u) (-cos(t), -sin(t), 0) + r sin(u) (-b sin(t), b cos(t), a) / sqrt(a² + b²), t, 0, 2π, u, 0, 2π)
```

Where $a$ is the distance of each helix from the axis of symmetry, $b$ is the height of each helix, and $r$ is the radius of the wire (which is the same as $a$ in figure above).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Given that the wires are tightly wound and can not seem to be twisted below a certain threshold H, is there a relation between D & L that would quantify that threshold?

Comment: This is unclear. why is H = D Cosθ at minimum? Or should it be H/2 = D Cosθ ??

Comment: Still can't wrap my head around as to why the length will be H+D and not just H the length of the axis. The figure makes it even more confusing. I was under the impression that the cross section is the figure 8 and distance between the 2 centers is always D. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kumar I realised that my answer for the minimum slope was wrong: I thus deleted it and added a figure which should explain why the length is $H+D\cos\theta$. Experimentally, minimum slope is 45° but I haven't a proof at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aretino. Awesome!  45° looks right too.

Comment: I edited my answer with a proof for the bound on the slope.

Comment: Thanks much. BTW, can you please tell how you made this very good illustration?

Comment: @Kumar I made it with GeoGebra, a very good free software for interactive geometry. I uploaded my file [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/zahbve6e) for you to explore or download.

Comment: @Artenio. Thanks for the link to file. But I couldn't play around with the values -- somehow I see just the figure without the equations. I wanted to play with different theta values. Also I wanted to see how the two end faces tilt wrt. each other. Can you please give the equations you used to create this figure? Or if you can create a you-tube video to show how you created this 3-D figure that would be wonderful. Many thanks.

Comment: @Kumar You can see the equations in the file: click the icon with three bars on top right of that page and choose "Save". If a pop-up windows appears asking you to sign in close it: a small dialogue window will then appear allowing you to save the file on your PC. Open it with your local copy of GeoGebra and select "Algebra" in the "View" menu: in the algebra window you'll find all the equations you need. In case you don't succeed let me know and I'll paste those equations into my answer.

Comment: @Artenio. I installed the Geogebra app locally and downloaded the file as .ggb, but on opening it get a Geogebra Error stating: Command curve. Illegal number of arguments 6. Thanks.

Comment: It's odd, are you sure you downloaded GeoGebra 5? Anyway I'll paste into my answer the definitions of the two surfaces.

Comment: @Artenio. I guess I had the version 4 installed. Thanks